# Is there any way I could replace the return type to the struct inheriting the interface, while still implementing the interface?

Tags: c#

I am currently working on my own game framework for C#, as part of a larger project of mine. 
I am trying to implement a Vector2 struct in a way where external libraries can extend it to fit their own needs, so I am using an interface. The interface looks similar to this:

```
public interface IVector2
{
   public double X { get; set; }
   public double Y { get; set; }
   public double Length { get; }

   //Other things here

   public IVector2 DistanceFrom(IVector2 from);

   //Other things here
}
```

The problem with this is that when I implement this into a struct, it keeps the IVector2 return on `DistanceFrom`, instead of replacing it with the struct that it is now in. This means that to use those methods, either all vectors have to be stored as their interface, or I have to cast. I don't want to do either. 
**Is there any way I could replace the return type to the struct inheriting the interface, while still implementing the interface?** 
I know using a class would solve this problem, but I don't want to use a class for something so common as a vector because of memory concerns. The game using my library could use *thousands* of vectors, and that could build up really quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered a way to do this. You have to require a generic to be passed (`IVector2<T>`), then assume that the generic is the type. You can then pass the generic via methods, and everything will work.

Comment: This looks similar to the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), which might have some useful inspirations too.

Comment: Yeah, it is similar. I didn't know something like that existed in C#, but I am glad it does.

Answer (score 1):

If you want libraries to be able to extend the structure by adding methods, without altering its storage, then you can do that via extension methods:

```
public static class VectorExtensions {
    public static Vector2 GetClockwisePerpendicular(this Vector2 v) {
        return new Vector2(v.y, -v.x);
    }
}
```

This will be available to code in that assembly as though it were a member of the type itself:

```
var up = new Vector2(0, 1);
var right = up.GetClockwisePerpendicular();
```

I'd recommend this approach over the interface route you're going now.

The main reason to use the interface would be if you want libraries to be able to change the storage of the `Vector2`, like adding new member variables, eg. a coordinate space or memoized length or unit direction.

The trouble with this is that now any method that accepts a `Vector2` has to be able to handle many different types with different storage sizes and layouts (dynamic polymorphism). This can't be done with raw value-type structs, so your struct gets "boxed" into a reference type object. That boxing entails a heap allocation for the garbage collector to track and reclaim, and extra indirection when manipulating the struct — costs you can most often avoid when working with data directly on the stack using a concrete struct type (ie. not an interface).

It's not a lot, so don't panic and remove interfaces everywhere! They're well worth their small overhead for many situations. But for something like a vector type that you're going to be using *a lot*, all this boxing and unboxing can add substantial overhead into your hot code paths.

For this reason, I would recommend not using an interface for your basic vector building blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know about the boxing that interfaces do, and I think it is worth the cost. I want my game framework to be as customizable as possible, and interfaces are the best way of doing that. I want to add optional extension libraries later so that you can code your game similar to MonoGame or OpenTK, with custom vectors that match those of said libraries.